# AJAX not being called WordPress .php file

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, wordpress

I have one clas and one .php file,

FIRST ONE, functions.php It's a .php file where it's my method that I am calling in the other class.

```
//PHP
add_action('wp_ajax_getJSONCurrencies', 'getJSONCurrencies');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_getJSONCurrencies', 'getJSONCurrencies');

function getJSONCurrencies () {
        $endpoint = $_POST['endp'];
        $access_key = $_POST['access'];
        $currencies = $_POST['curren'];
        $source = $_POST['sour'];
        $format = 1;

        // Initialize CURL:
        $ch = curl_init('https://apilayer.net/api/'.$endpoint.'?access_key='.$access_key.'&currencies='.$currencies.'&source='.$source.'&format='.$format.'');
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

        // Store the data:
        $json = curl_exec($ch);
        curl_close($ch);

        // Decode JSON response:
        echo json_decode($json, true);

    }
```

And my second Class, custom-wc-widget...php where I call my first class function.

```
jQuery( document.body ).bind( \'bejob_price_slider_create bejob_price_slider_slide\', function( event, min, max ) {

        var simMoneda = jQuery(\'.woocommerce-currency-switcher-form > select option:selected\').text();
        var simbolo = simMoneda.split(",");

        simMoneda = simbolo[1].trim();

        var endpoint = \'live\';
        var access_key = \'0a85b3479a1a24ceaba1d04f030e7028\';
        var currencies = \'USD,ARS,CLP,PEN,COP,MXN,PAB\';
        var source = \'EUR\';

        jQuery.ajax({
           type:\'POST\',
           url: \'ajaxurl\',
           //url: \'https://apilayer.net/api/\' + endpoint +\'?access_key=\' + access_key + \'&currencies=\' + currencies + \'&source=\' + source + \'&format=\' + 1,
           data: {
                endp: endpoint,
                access: access_key,
                curren: currencies,
                sour: source,
                action: \'getJSONCurrencies\'
            },
            dataType: "json",
            success: function(data) {
                 debugger;
               console.log(data);
            }
        });

        if ( min == 0) {
                jQuery( \'.bejob_price_slider_amount span.from\' ).html( "Gratis");

        } else {
                jQuery( \'.bejob_price_slider_amount span.from\' ).html( min + simMoneda );

        }
        jQuery( \'.bejob_price_slider_amount span.to\' ).html( max + simMoneda );

        jQuery( document.body ).trigger( \'price_slider_updated\', [ min, max ] );
    });
```

This second class has \' symbols because it's inside a echo php, my idea is to send the data in the ajax statement to my function **getJSONCurrencies** and then at the success function from the ajax method receive the JSON object I am going to use on my web page.

The problem is when I run the debugger it never enters in my Ajax Method and I dont know why it isn't entering there.

Comment: Move your javascript into an external javascript file.  Use [wp_localize_script](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_localize_script) to set up your data (such as endpoint, access key, currencies, etc).  That way you don't have to embed it in a PHP echo.  This will dramatically simplify debugging / maintaining your code.  (Here's a good writeup: https://pippinsplugins.com/use-wp_localize_script-it-is-awesome/)

Comment: And as a side-note, you are calling these "classes", but they aren't [classes](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.basic.php).

Comment: Yeah I know they are not classes, but I use this term to distinguish between both .php files.

Comment: Terms matter very much in programming.  I'd suggest using class properly, and say "Files" if you mean different files.

Comment: Well as u wish, my FIRST class .php and my SECOND .php file. About the first question, yeah I know but it isn't my code, I can debugg it perfectly but the problem that it never enters at the ajax mehtod.

Comment: Here's the problem: You say "Class".  Your question does not contain a class.  Your AJAX action does not reference a class.  But you said "Class", so my first reaction is that your AJAX action is wrong, and needs to be rewritten to `add_action('wp_ajax_getJSONCurrencies', array('className', 'getJSONCurrencies'));` in order to work with a class (by the name of "className" in my example).

Comment: class CustomWidgetPriceFilterBejob extends WC_Widget_Bejob {

Comment: That's the class called custom-wc-widget, there I have a construct and my functions, then I have another .php file called functions.php where I have the function that I called in ajax method.

Comment: Now I'm very confused.  If you are using classes, please edit your question and show the relevant parts of the class(es) so we can help.

Answer (score 0):

How do you call the jquery? If you have another function please edit your question.

try like below code using wp_localize_script:

```
add_action('wp_ajax_getJSONCurrencies', 'getJSONCurrencies');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_getJSONCurrencies', 'getJSONCurrencies');

wp_enqueue_script('getJSONCurrencies', get_template_directory_uri().'/js/getJSONCurrencies.js', array('jquery'), '1.0', true );
wp_localize_script('getJSONCurrencies', 'ajax_var', array(
    'url' => admin_url('admin-ajax.php'),
    'nonce' => wp_create_nonce('ajax-nonce')
));
```